# TermFreqVector lucene .net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I can get docs by category like this:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);

                Term t = new Term("category", "Feline");
                Query query = new TermQuery(t);
                Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);

                for (int c = 0; c < hits.Length(); c++)
                {
                    Document d = hits.Doc(c);
                    Console.WriteLine(c + " " + d.GetField("category").StringValue());
                }
```

Now I would like to obtain the TermFreqVector for the docs in hits. I would usually do this like so:

```
for (int c = 0; c < searcher.MaxDoc(); c++)
                {
                    TermFreqVector TermFreqVector = IndexReader.GetTermFreqVector(c, "content");

                    String[] terms = TermFreqVector.GetTerms();//get the terms
                    int[] freqs = TermFreqVector.GetTermFrequencies();//
                }
```

However, I am not sure how to do it in my scenario (i.e. just get them for the docs in hits). The docs also have a db pk.

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to `IndexReader.GetTermFreqVector` ("c" in your example) is the document number. `hits.id(c)` will return the ID of the cth result. So you'd do something like:

```
int Id = hits.id(c);
TermFreqVector TermFreqVector = IndexReader.GetTermFreqVector(Id, "content");
// etc.
```

(As a side note: the Hits class is deprecated; you probably want to use something like `HitCollector` or a different search overload instead.)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at this. I am using Lucene .Net - probably takes a while until hits is depreceated ...

Comment: @csetzkorn: It's officially deprecated in 2.9.3, which is what lucene.net uses. You're right that it won't be removed entirely until 3.0. (It's slow in any case, regardless of whether it's officially supported or not.)